# Differences between categorical classification algorithms

Tags: classification, svm, multinomial-distribution, naive-bayes, intuition

Given data where the class is categorical (finite and discrete), there are multiple ways to come up with a classifier. One could use **multinomial logistic regression**, or **support vector clustering** (implemented, for example, as SVC in scikit-learn). What is the fundamental difference between these two algorithms? When is one better than the other? Are they fundamentally trying to minimize a different type of error?

An entirely different approach is generative algorithms, and in particular **naive Bayes**. When is that appropriate as opposed to the discriminative alogirthms above?

Answer (score 1):

Your question really requires more of an answer than can really fit in a space like this.  Luckily there is a good book on the topic and an electronic copy can be downloaded for free.  See [The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/).

The book has sections/chapters on each of the topics you ask about.